# How do I store this linked list in an object array?

Tags: java, linked-list

I have this class called Sorting that takes in a set of integers from the user, stores them in a linked list, then checks to see if they are stored in an increasing order.

Right now it has the ability to take in one list of integers and store it, then check if it is sorted. I need the ability to store two separate lists and check them both, but I'm not sure how to go about storing them.

I assume i'm supposed to store it in an object array but how do I go about storing the `IntNode` class object in the storage array?

**Here's the Sorting class:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Sorting {

    public static IntNode[] storage = new IntNode[2];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        IntNode head;
        head = new IntNode(0, null);
        int headCounter = 0;
        int searchNumber = 0;
        int nextInt;
        int storageNumber = 0;

        System.out.println("Please enter a seqeunce of integer numbers. When you are finished, enter a negative number");
        while (input.hasNextInt()) {
            nextInt = input.nextInt();
            if (nextInt >= 0) {
                if (headCounter == 0) {
                    head = new IntNode(nextInt, null);
                    searchNumber = nextInt;
                    headCounter++;
                    storageNumber++;
                } else {
                    IntNode selection = IntNode.listSearch(head, searchNumber);
                    selection.addNodeAfter(nextInt);
                    searchNumber = nextInt;
                    storageNumber++;
                }
            } else {
                headCounter = 0;
            }
        }

        for (IntNode cursor = head; cursor != null; cursor = cursor.getLink())
        System.out.print(cursor.getData() + " ");

        System.out.println(isSorted(head));

    }
    // Checks the linked list to see if the integers are sorted in increasing order
    // @param IntNode head
    //      The head of the linked list being checked
    // @return 
    //      The method returns true if the linked list is sorted in increasing order, and false if the 
    //      list is not sorted in an increasing order
    public static boolean isSorted(IntNode head) {
        int numCheckPrevious = 0;
        for (IntNode cursor = head; cursor != null; cursor = cursor.getLink()) {
            if (cursor.getData() > numCheckPrevious) {
                numCheckPrevious = cursor.getData();
                continue;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

**And here is the IntNode class that is storing the integers in a linked list:**

```
// File: IntNode.java 
/******************************************************************************
* An IntNode provides a node for a linked list with 
* integer data in each node.
*
* @note
*   Lists of nodes can be made of any length, limited only by the amount of
*   free memory in the heap. But beyond Integer.MAX_VALUE (2,147,483,647),
*   the answer from listLength is incorrect because of arithmetic
*   overflow. 
******************************************************************************/
public class IntNode
{
   // Invariant of the IntNode class:
   //   1. The node's integer data is in the instance variable data.
   //   2. For the final node of a list, the link part is null.
   //      Otherwise, the link part is a reference to the
   //      next node of the list.
   private int data;
   private IntNode link;   


   /**
   * Initialize a node with a specified initial data and link to the next
   * node. Note that the initialLink may be the null reference, 
   * which indicates that the new node has nothing after it.
   * @param initialData
   *   the initial data of this new node
   * @param initialLink
   *   a reference to the node after this new node--this reference may be null
   *   to indicate that there is no node after this new node.
   * @postcondition
   *   This node contains the specified data and link to the next node.
   **/   
   public IntNode(int initialData, IntNode initialLink)
   {
      data = initialData;
      link = initialLink;
   }


   /**
   * Modification method to add a new node after this node.   
   * @param item
   *   the data to place in the new node
   * @postcondition
   *   A new node has been created and placed after this node.
   *   The data for the new node is item. Any other nodes
   *   that used to be after this node are now after the new node.
   * @exception OutOfMemoryError
   *   Indicates that there is insufficient memory for a new 
   *   IntNode. 
   **/
   public void addNodeAfter(int item)   
   {
      link = new IntNode(item, link);
   }          


   /**
   * Accessor method to get the data from this node.   
   * @param - none
   * @return
   *   the data from this node
   **/
   public int getData( )   
   {
      return data;
   }


   /**
   * Accessor method to get a reference to the next node after this node. 
   * @param - none
   * @return
   *   a reference to the node after this node (or the null reference if there
   *   is nothing after this node)
   **/
   public IntNode getLink( )
   {
      return link;                                               
   } 


   /**
   * Copy a list.
   * @param source
   *   the head of a linked list that will be copied (which may be
   *   an empty list in where source is null)
   * @return
   *   The method has made a copy of the linked list starting at 
   *   source. The return value is the head reference for the
   *   copy. 
   * @exception OutOfMemoryError
   *   Indicates that there is insufficient memory for the new list.   
   **/ 
   public static IntNode listCopy(IntNode source)
   {
      IntNode copyHead;
      IntNode copyTail;

      // Handle the special case of the empty list.
      if (source == null)
         return null;

      // Make the first node for the newly created list.
      copyHead = new IntNode(source.data, null);
      copyTail = copyHead;

      // Make the rest of the nodes for the newly created list.
      while (source.link != null)
      {
         source = source.link;
         copyTail.addNodeAfter(source.data);
         copyTail = copyTail.link;
      }

      // Return the head reference for the new list.
    return copyHead;  // *   This node contains the specified data and link to the next node.

   }


   /**
   * Copy a list, returning both a head and tail reference for the copy.
   * @param source
   *   the head of a linked list that will be copied (which may be
   *   an empty list in where source is null)
   * @return
   *   The method has made a copy of the linked list starting at 
   *   source.  The return value is an
   *   array where the [0] element is a head reference for the copy and the [1]
   *   element is a tail reference for the copy.
   * @exception OutOfMemoryError
   *   Indicates that there is insufficient memory for the new list.   
   **/
   public static IntNode[ ] listCopyWithTail(IntNode source)
   {
      IntNode copyHead;
      IntNode copyTail;
      IntNode[ ] answer = new IntNode[2];

      // Handle the special case of the empty list.   
      if (source == null)
         return answer; // The answer has two null references .

      // Make the first node for the newly created list.
      copyHead = new IntNode(source.data, null);
      copyTail = copyHead;

      // Make the rest of the nodes for the newly created list.
      while (source.link != null)
      {
         source = source.link;
         copyTail.addNodeAfter(source.data);
         copyTail = copyTail.link;
      }

      // Return the head and tail references.
      answer[0] = copyHead;
      answer[1] = copyTail;
      return answer;
   }


   /**
   * Compute the number of nodes in a linked list.
   * @param head
   *   the head reference for a linked list (which may be an empty list
   *   with a null head)
   * @return
   *   the number of nodes in the list with the given head 
   * @note
   *   A wrong answer occurs for lists longer than Int.MAX_VALUE.     
   **/   
   public static int listLength(IntNode head)
   {
      IntNode cursor;
      int answer;

      answer = 0;
      for (cursor = head; cursor != null; cursor = cursor.link)
         answer++;

      return answer;
   }


   /**
   * Copy part of a list, providing a head and tail reference for the new copy. 
   * @param start/end
   *   references to two nodes of a linked list
   * @param copyHead/copyTail
   *   the method sets these to refer to the head and tail node of the new
   *   list that is created
   * @precondition
   *   start and end are non-null references to nodes
   *   on the same linked list,
   *   with the start node at or before the end node. 
   * @return
   *   The method has made a copy of the part of a linked list, from the
   *   specified start node to the specified end node. The return value is an
   *   array where the [0] component is a head reference for the copy and the
   *   [1] component is a tail reference for the copy.
   * @exception IllegalArgumentException
   *   Indicates that start and end are not references
   *   to nodes on the same list.
   * @exception NullPointerException
   *   Indicates that start is null.
   * @exception OutOfMemoryError
   *   Indicates that there is insufficient memory for the new list.    
   **/   
   public static IntNode[ ] listPart(IntNode start, IntNode end)
   {
      IntNode copyHead;
      IntNode copyTail;
      IntNode cursor;
      IntNode[ ] answer = new IntNode[2];

      // Make the first node for the newly created list. Notice that this will
      // cause a NullPointerException if start is null.
      copyHead = new IntNode(start.data, null);
      copyTail = copyHead;
      cursor = start;

      // Make the rest of the nodes for the newly created list.
      while (cursor != end)
      {
         cursor = cursor.link;
         if (cursor == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException
            ("end node was not found on the list");
         copyTail.addNodeAfter(cursor.data);
         copyTail = copyTail.link;
      }

      // Return the head and tail references
      answer[0] = copyHead;
      answer[1] = copyTail;
      return answer;
   }        


   /**
   * Find a node at a specified position in a linked list.
   * @param head
   *   the head reference for a linked list (which may be an empty list in
   *   which case the head is null)
   * @param position
   *   a node number
   * @precondition
   *   position > 0.
   * @return
   *   The return value is a reference to the node at the specified position in
   *   the list. (The head node is position 1, the next node is position 2, and
   *   so on.) If there is no such position (because the list is too short),
   *   then the null reference is returned.
   * @exception IllegalArgumentException
   *   Indicates that position is not positive.    
   **/   
   public static IntNode listPosition(IntNode head, int position)
   {
      IntNode cursor;
      int i;

      if (position <= 0)
           throw new IllegalArgumentException("position is not positive");

      cursor = head;
      for (i = 1; (i < position) && (cursor != null); i++)
         cursor = cursor.link;

      return cursor;
   }


   /**
   * Search for a particular piece of data in a linked list.
   * @param head
   *   the head reference for a linked list (which may be an empty list in
   *   which case the head is null)
   * @param target
   *   a piece of data to search for
   * @return
   *   The return value is a reference to the first node that contains the
   *   specified target. If there is no such node, the null reference is 
   *   returned.     
   **/   
   public static IntNode listSearch(IntNode head, int target)
   {
      IntNode cursor;

      for (cursor = head; cursor != null; cursor = cursor.link)
         if (target == cursor.data)
            return cursor;

      return null;
   }


   /**
   * Modification method to remove the node after this node.   
   * @param - none
   * @precondition
   *   This node must not be the tail node of the list.
   * @postcondition
   *   The node after this node has been removed from the linked list.
   *   If there were further nodes after that one, they are still
   *   present on the list.
   * @exception NullPointerException
   *   Indicates that this was the tail node of the list, so there is nothing
   *   after it to remove.
   **/
   public void removeNodeAfter( )   
   {
      link = link.link;
   }          


   /**
   * Modification method to set the data in this node.   
   * @param newData
   *   the new data to place in this node
   * @postcondition
   *   The data of this node has been set to newData.
   **/
   public void setData(int newData)   
   {
      data = newData;
   }                                                               


   /**
   * Modification method to set the link to the next node after this node.
   * @param newLink
   *   a reference to the node that should appear after this node in the linked
   *   list (or the null reference if there is no node after this node)
   * @postcondition
   *   The link to the node after this node has been set to newLink.
   *   Any other node (that used to be in this link) is no longer connected to
   *   this node.
   **/
   public void setLink(IntNode newLink)
   {                    
      link = newLink;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To insert a node into the storage array, first assume that you have not yet initialized your linked list:

```
storage[0] = new IntNode(head_data, head_ptr);
```

If you already initialized your Linked List, and it starts with some `IntNode head`, you can store it in the array like so:

```
storage[0] = head;
```

If you have two linked lists initialized already, you can store them like so:

```
storage[0] = head1;
storage[1] = head2;
```

Your `IntNode[]` array is already initialized above your main method, which is why you'd be able to simply set the separate indeces of the array.

The `storage` array here will work like other arrays (ints, chars, etc.) with one crucial difference - if you insert an `IntNode` into the array, and change it outside of your array, it will be changed inside your array as well.

Comment: Glad I could help :)